# Converting html5 canvas to android

Tags: android, html, canvas, port

I've been spending the last week to develop a little platform game with HTML5's canvas element.
I was thinking about trying to port my game to the Android platform, but came across a few questions.
I have never done any Android programming, nor Java!
Only Javascript and PHP - but belive I have a good understanding of programming in general.

1. Will I be able to use the same procedure for building my game? Here I mean, my way of drawing everything on the screen/canvas. The rest is just calculations, and should be easily ported?

   - Every game loop I draw the background image, all items, and both players.
2. What would be the best way to control a platform game on a touchscreen? I was thinking about detecting parts of the screen individually.

   - Finger on right side: Walk right
   - Finger on left side: Walk left
   - Tap screen: jump
   - 2 Finger tap: place bomb

Any suggestions or links are appreciated. Let me know if you need to see any code or an example of the game.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you look into using cocoonjs with your experience in php/javascript. It is really new so there is not a lot of documentation but if you pick through there demo code I am sure you will be fine.

http://wiki.ludei.com/cocoonjs:devguide

Answer (score 1):

Am not being specific here but I think you can look up on Appcelerator Titanium and Phonegap to write Android apps using PHP and Javascript. There is a difference between how they function and what they do, though.

Here are some links:

http://www.appcelerator.com/products/titanium-mobile-application-development/ 
http://www.phonegap.com/home

Comment: Do you anything about performance on Android contra native Java?

Comment: Also, will it be possible to launch an applikation like this through android market?